# Thread is not executing in spite of using method join

Tags: java, multithreading, join

I don't quite understand why I get this output for this code:

```
public class Example {

    static void threadMessage(String message) {
        String threadName =
            Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.format("%s: %s%n", threadName, message);
    }

    private static class MessageLoop implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            String importantInfo[] = {
                "Line 1",
                "Line 2",
                "Line 3",
                "Line 4"
            };
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i< importantInfo.length; i++) {
                    // Pause for 4 seconds
                    Thread.sleep(4000);
                    // Print a message
                    threadMessage(importantInfo[i]);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                ;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {


        threadMessage("Starting MessageLoop thread");
        Thread t = new Thread(new MessageLoop());
        t.start();

        threadMessage("Waiting for MessageLoop thread to finish");

        while (t.isAlive()) {
            threadMessage("Still waiting...");
            // Wait maximum of 1 second
            // for MessageLoop thread
            // to finish.
            t.join(1000);
        }
        threadMessage("Finally!");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
main: Starting MessageLoop thread
main: Waiting for MessageLoop thread to finish
main: Still waiting...
main: Still waiting...
main: Still waiting...
main: Still waiting...
main: Still waiting...
Thread-0: Line 1
main: Still waiting...
main: Still waiting...
main: Still waiting...
main: Still waiting...
Thread-0: Line 2
main: Still waiting...
main: Still waiting...
main: Still waiting...
Thread-0: Line 3
main: Still waiting...
main: Still waiting...
main: Still waiting...
main: Still waiting...
Thread-0: Line 4
main: Finally!
```

if I write this statement inside the loop, Thread main continues with its execution. It is not supposed that thread main should continue with its execution after that thread t has finished?

t.join(1000);

However, the bucle continues its executing. To my knowledge these 2 lines belong to thread main
- while (t.isAlive())
- threadMessage("Still waiting...")

I'm trying to understand an example of this link:

[Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/simple.html)

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Comment: What don't you understand in the output? What output would you expect and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `join()` method's documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join(long)). This is what is says:

> Waits at most millis milliseconds for this thread to die.

You are passing 1000 to `join()`, that means, main thread will wait 1 second at most, before continuing, regardless of whether `thread t` is complete. Thread `t` has sleep timeout of 4 seconds and hence, main thread will always complete before `t` (after join timing out).

If you want main thread to wait forever then, you need to use `join()` (i.e. without any argument).

Answer (score 1):

```
while (t.isAlive()) {
    threadMessage("Still waiting...");
    // Wait maximum of 1 second
    // for MessageLoop thread
    // to finish.
    t.join(1000);
}
```

`t.join(1000)` means waits 1000 milliseconds for thread `t` to die. `t` will not die until it prints all lines. The scenario is `t.join(1000)` timedout every second and t is still alive(because it sleeps 4 seconds each time print one line). `join(1000)` timedout and `t.isAlive()` is true, therefore your main thread would print out `Still waiting`.. Once thread `t` has finished its job, `t.isAlive()` will be false and it breaks the while loop then print `Finally`